# Overwrite content of a file in Angular

Tags: angularjs, electron, read-write

I want to know is there any way to **change/overwrite** the content of a file , which I am calling from my local storage ?

I have some values in my `$scope` model and I need to replace the contents of a file. I have used few methods even external libraries like [fs js](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and similar , but the file is getting downloaded.

I don't want to show file is getting download , in case it must operate in background and replace the contents in the original file without getting a copy of it.

Suggest me some method , I am stuck  here for a while now.

Comment: You want to read & then overwrite a file on any PC (in the background) without it showing on the browser... you want this behavior for anyone/everyone who is accessing your web application... are you using Node JS?

Comment: @AIqbal I am able to read then making changes and storing it in a model .yes it is showing in the browser. Now I want to replace the content that is in the file which I am reading. Yes I am using Node.JS

Comment: the Node JS code executes on the server and can store file on the server (without the user knowing)... the AngularJS code runs on the client's browser and if you want to save a file on the client's browser, it will show up to the user... this is how web development works, unless there is some high tech Hacking stuff which can by-pass this...

Comment: @AIqbal So you mean to say there is no way to overwrite a file in the background in client  side ? That means browser don't allow to do that. It will make the file download. So , Is it possible in electron desktop app ?

Comment: what is an electron desktop app?

Comment: @AIqbal Electron framework based desktop application. https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Haven't tried electron myself... and looking at it, I think you'll get what you want with it. An electron expert might be able to give a definitive answer (if you can tag your question with #ElectronJS to help it more searchable)